# type aliasing ("using") within same vs. hierarchical namespaces

Tags: c#, typedef

Please compare these definitions below. What is the problem with second definition?

I want to use type1 within definition of another type in the same namespace, how should I really do that?

**1st definition:**

```
namespace parent
{
    using type1 = Int16;

    namespace child
    {
    using list1 = List<type1>; //OK!
    }
}
```

**2nd definition:**

```
namespace sibling
{
    using type1 = Int16;
    using list1 = List<type1>; //error: the type or namespace 'type1' could not be found.
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
using type1 = Int16;
using list1 = List<type1>; //error: the type or namespace 'type1' could not be found 

namespace myNameSpace
{
   using dic1 = Dictionary <int, list1>;
}
```

Comment: As the "EDIT" section suggests, please do not limit the usage scenario to two type aliases only, for example a third alias may need to reference the second alias as well (dic1 in this example)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare using statements and use them in the same block. For example, try this:

```
using System;
using type1 = Int16;

namespace sibling
{
}
```

This will give you an error stating that Int16 is unknown for the type1 declaration. Move it inside the namespace though and all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
using type1 = Int16;
namespace sibling
{

    using list1 = List<type1>;
}
```

Continue to answering your question in nodes...
I am really not sure that such aliasing will gain a better code readability. So suppose a case when you have the following.

```
namespace a
{
    using type1 = int16;
    namespace b
    {
          using list1 = List<int16>
          namespace c
          {
               var dictionary1 = Dictionary<type1, list1>
          }
    }
    using list1 = List<object>;
}
```

Who knows, that might be the reason that such a defs were forbidden in C#.

But some code readability still can be archieved with OOP methodology. so for example your dictionary can be defined the following way.

```
public class MyDictionary<T> : Dictionary<T, List<T>>
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new MyDictionary<int>();
        }
    }
```

and after that there is still a way to be creative with aliasing. :)

Comment: This also kind of parent-child where the parent is the "Global" level namespace. Suppose I want now to introduce another type based on list1, I will come across the same issue, for example:


using dic1 = Dictionary <int, list1>

Comment: Could you share the way of your thoughts. why do you need this? It could happen that there might be another way for doign such a thing...

Comment: I want to avoid poorly readable codes such as:
var x = new Dictionary < int , List <int> >, I want to give the type a meaningful name